# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [" all of a sudden in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

It was working fine up until very recently.  Chrome tells me this is incorrect with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ["

```
$.each($regions, function(index, [value1, value2]) { 
    $("#regions .options").children("#r").append("<div class='brick' id='" + index + "' name='" + value2 + "'>" + value1 + "</div>");
});
```

Firefox and firebug do not raise a stink and everything is working alright.  I don't understand what happened in Chrome.  I swear this exact code worked before.

Chrome v.12.0.742.122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare a function with parameters like that([value1, value2]). Try this

```
$.each($regions, function(index, values) { 
    $("#regions .options").children("#r").append("<div class='brick' id='" + index + "' name='" + values[1] + "'>" + values[0] + "</div>");
});
```

Comment: Even if $regions is a hash? like $regions = {}; $regions['1'] = "Asia","as"]; $regions['8'] = ["Australia and Oceania","au"]; etc...?

Comment: In that case you will get any array as the seccond parameter in for each handler. You have to iterate through that array and build the string.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  I guess I dreamed up testing it on Chrome.